# Django Annotation Aggregation Speed

Tags: python, django

I'm using the following annotation to generate a count of related objects in a database:

```
challenges = Challenge.objects.annotate(
    solve_count=Count('solves', filter=Q(solves__correct=True)),
    unlock_time_surpassed=Case(
        When(release_time__lte=timezone.now(), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=models.BooleanField(),
    ),
    votes_positive=Count("votes", filter=Q(votes__positive=True), distinct=True),
    votes_negative=Count("votes", filter=Q(votes__positive=False), distinct=True),
)
```

The query this generates takes around 2000ms to execute with 1000 Challenges and 1 million Solves.
if I replace `solve_count=Count('solves', filter=Q(solves__correct=True)),` with `solve_count=Value(0, output_field=models.IntegerField()),` the time spent on queries goes from 2000ms to 50ms (but obviously the solve count is lost in the process)

Is there anything I can do to increase the performance of the Count operation?

Comment: What are your indexes on the challenges and solves tables?

Comment: Make sure `solves.challenge_id` (or whatever you're calling it) is indexed. But one thing I like to do in this situation is just write the raw SQL myself and compare execution time, just to see. Have you tried that?